# Received memory warning when use MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios7

Getting "Received memory warning" when take the thumbnails form MPMoviePlayerController and application is crashed.

I am using the code :

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    for (int i = 0; i < pickedVideoAssetDuration; i ++){

        UIImage *singleFrameImage = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:i timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
        // checks whether the thumbnails are properly extracted or not
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0f);
        [singleFrameImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        NSLog(@"newSize >60 : %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newImage.size));
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        // checks whether the thumbnails are properly extracted or not
        if(newImage)
            [durationArray addObject:newImage];
        else
            NSLog(@"nil thumbnail");

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          [self  designthumbScroll:thumbImageCount];
                      });
  }}
```

Will appreciated if any help :)

Comment: please put warning here ..

Comment: "Received memory warning"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Videos are expensive to load in memory in general.

Maybe try adding an @autoreleasepool to the inside of your loop to release memory slightly faster:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pickedVideoAssetDuration; i ++)
{
    @autoreleasepool{
        // your existing code
    }
}
```

Otherwise, look at the rest of your code and see what memory you can release at the time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked for small loop e.g.: 1 to 60, long loop is not working. There are same warning.

Comment: If thats the case, maybe break it up into a series of smaller loops?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get thumbnails by

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourVideoFileName"];

    UIImage * thumbnailImg = [self getThumbNail:newPath];
```

And method code

```
-(UIImage *)getThumbNail:(NSString *)stringPath
{
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    [player stop];
    return thumbnail;
}
```